# How to create onSubmit with Material-UI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm fairly new to node.js / react / material-ui. I've been following a guide to try setting up a website and have been getting on pretty well. I decided to include material-ui for snazzy components (not part of the guide) and then got stuck because I can't seem to fire custom functions whilst using a themed ui.

With the below code, I can create everything fine if I ditch the 'classes' props. I can add my function and everything works. But I obviously lose all my styling if I do this.

```js
const styles = theme => ({
    // Styling - omitted
});

const Login = (props) => {

    const {classes} = props;

    return(
        <div>
            <Paper className={classes.root}>
                <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField
                        id="email"
                        label="Email"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        InputProps={{
                            className: classes.input
                        }}
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        autoComplete="email"
                        margin="normal"
                        variant="outlined"
                        required
                        autoFocus
                    />
                    <TextField
                        id="outlined"
                        label="Password"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        InputProps={{
                            className: classes.input
                        }}
                        type="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        margin="normal"
                        variant="outlined"
                        required
                    />
                    <Typography className={classes.divider} />
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        variant="contained"
                        color="inherit"
                        className={classes.button}
                    >
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
}

Login.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Login);
```

I'm trying to combine the styling as well as being able to fire a custom function to submit the form data. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: For the submit part, you can pass an `onSubmit` prop to your `form`, it must be a function that takes a single parameter `event`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The class property/ styles shouldn't have any effect on form submission custom function. If you think that ditching the 'class props' you can get a custom function to work - post your code so we can help you further. [Your code is missing submit function]

Here is one way to add custom submit function

```
const Login = (props) => {
const {classes} = props;
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log( 'Email:', email, 'Password: ', password); 
       // You should see email and password in console.
       // ..code to submit form to backend here...

    }

    return( <div >
            <Paper className={classes.root}>
                <form className={classes.container} onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                    <TextField
                        ....                   
                        value={email}
                        onInput={ e=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        .....

                    />
                    <TextField
                        ....
                        value={password}
                        onInput={ e=>setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        ....
                    />
                    <Typography className={classes.divider} />
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                         ....
                        className={classes.button}
                    >
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Heck sweet. I didn't quite know where to start, but this should get me going. I'll give this a try later on, thank you!